# cor() heatmap that also takes into account lag?

Tags: r, correlation, cross-correlation

I have this data frame:

```r
> head(calcium)
     Cell 1    Cell 2     Cell 3    Cell 4    Cell 5    Cell 6    Cell 7    Cell 8    Cell 9   Cell 10
1 0.4672073 0.5844194 0.53550783 0.5364516 0.3470978 0.2802241 0.3965193 0.4651296 0.4871049 0.5685573
2 0.6724369 0.5549080 0.46405108 0.5231966 0.3634458 0.4480713 0.4991682 0.5315563 0.5486042 0.5294624
3 0.4596055 0.4670149 0.49120023 0.4395472 0.2961227 0.2931165 0.3343016 0.3347550 0.5988327 0.3738076
4 0.5033532 0.6265054 0.38094926 0.5931815 0.4030199 0.3461845 0.4966594 0.5039769 0.6795089 0.4875191
5 0.2544972 0.3734030 0.06739901 0.2006546 0.1038821 0.2315288 0.1704387 0.1001154 0.3799489 0.3224333
    Cell 11   Cell 12   Cell 13   Cell 14   Cell 15    Cell 16   Cell 17   Cell 18   Cell 19   Cell 20
1 0.6870339 0.6695488 0.6130446 0.5356461 0.6609977 0.58372848 0.5422807 0.5344803 0.6320900 0.6294263
2 0.5734583 0.6547612 0.5392496 0.5330794 0.5704163 0.29659694 0.5567181 0.5780661 0.4010656 0.5863210
3 0.3404278 0.4653025 0.4841558 0.4371394 0.4779519 0.37612878 0.5571457 0.4525741 0.3330830 0.6095697
4 0.5570465 0.5552679 0.5799134 0.5745080 0.5390752 0.44927465 0.5118969 0.5618096 0.4442722 0.5840596
5 0.2730119 0.2671422 0.1901299 0.2949408 0.2715825 0.03302615 0.2712914 0.2962793 0.2137080 0.3243795

> tail(calcium)
        Cell 1    Cell 2    Cell 3    Cell 4    Cell 5    Cell 6    Cell 7    Cell 8    Cell 9   Cell 10
1495 0.4740832 0.5869490 0.5582463 0.6920769 0.5148404 0.4017368 0.6079173 0.7788185 0.8114776 0.7092727
1496 0.6341606 0.5733480 0.4622866 0.6170735 0.3884858 0.3778201 0.5342382 0.6239193 0.5823868 0.6487626
1497 0.3662752 0.4143892 0.2904592 0.4388380 0.2732026 0.4264538 0.4004278 0.4336887 0.3919094 0.4598705
1498 0.4719526 0.5387774 0.4595078 0.4988954 0.4979742 0.3102995 0.5260781 0.5331988 0.6804864 0.6189913
1499 0.4194409 0.5404455 0.4455472 0.5634257 0.4054463 0.4645974 0.4627777 0.5951874 0.4545299 0.6653680
       Cell 11   Cell 12   Cell 13   Cell 14   Cell 15   Cell 16   Cell 17   Cell 18   Cell 19   Cell 20
1495 0.6556259 0.7681060 0.7380664 0.7464327 0.5121680 0.6313292 0.6928669 0.7497219 0.5277792 0.7770823
1496 0.4813021 0.6268656 0.5539104 0.5806629 0.3948412 0.3627633 0.5811911 0.6131842 0.3701380 0.6591560
1497 0.3969300 0.5247286 0.4840403 0.4693218 0.4129616 0.3213437 0.5072689 0.5465302 0.2863405 0.4979315
1498 0.4925699 0.5820069 0.6174026 0.5797521 0.4415087 0.3831081 0.6320489 0.6061551 0.5626544 0.7134859
1499 0.4026728 0.5014044 0.5536220 0.5139246 0.4354147 0.3987318 0.5499019 0.5411839 0.4232987 0.5824049
```

and I would like to get a cross-correlation matrix, like the one I get with:

```r
library(gplots)
Colors=c("blue","yellow","red")
Colors=colorRampPalette(Colors)(100)
heatmap.2(as.matrix(cor(calcium)), dendrogram = "none",
          col = Colors, trace = "none", density.info =  "none")
```

but this time, I'd like it to consider a lag of 1. How can I do that?

Comment: Can you clarify/confirm? Do you want to compute the lag-1 cross-correlation for each pair of columns (e.g.) `cor(calcium[-1,1], calcium[-nrow(calcium),2])` (i.e. the lag-1 cross-correlation between the first and second columns? (Or equivalently `ccf(calcium[,1],calcium[,2],lag.max=1)$acf[3,1,1]`) ? I don't think there will be a built-in solution, I think you'll have to loop over the pairs of columns yourself.  What have you tried so far ... ?

Comment: Yes, I want to cross-correlate between each pair of columns, with a max lag of 1. It seems that ``` ccf(calcium[,1],calcium[,2],lag.max=1)$acf[3,1,1]``` might be it, but I don't understand the ```$acf[3,1,1]``` bit? could you explain? Also, in case of a loop, how would I go in that case? I know ```for``` loops, but just the basics and I'm not sure how I can refer to the two columns in this case. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make up example data:

```r
nc <- 20
calcium <- matrix(rnorm(nc^2), nc, nc)
```

Loop over the entire matrix (CCF(i,j,1) is not identical to CCF(j,i,1), so we need to compute the whole matrix, not just one half), computing correlation matrix:

```
cmat <- matrix(NA,nc,nc)
for (i in 1:nc) {
   for (j in 1:nc) {
      cmat[i,j] <- cor(calcium[-1,i], calcium[-nrow(calcium),j])
      ## or: ccf(calcium[,i],calcium[,j],lag.max=1)$acf[3,1,1]
   }
}
```

Then use `cmat` in place of `cor(calcium)` in your plotting code.

---

There are (at least) two ways to compute `CCF(i,j,1)`.

- `cor(x[-1,i], x[-nrow(x),j])` sets up the lagged version of the columns manually (by excluding the first element for one column and the last element for the other)
- `ccf(x[,i],x[,j],lag.max=1)$acf[3,1,1]` uses the built-in `ccf()` function. The results are returned in the `$acf` element of a list, which is a (lag)x1x1 array, where the first dimension holds the range of lags. When `lag.max=1` the cross-correlations are computed for lags -1, 0, 1, so the third element is the +1 lag result.

Comment: Thanks, that works and you explained it really well! I was wondering, would there be a way to do such lag-1 cross correlation and then only select the lag that gives higher correlation? E.g.:

```
> ccfccf <- ccf(calcium[,1], calcium[,2], lag.max = 1)
> ccfccf
Autocorrelations of series ‘X’, by lag

   -1     0     1 
0.279 0.723 0.266

```
And select the 0.723, because it's the highest in that ±1 range.
I was thinking of a function like this:

```
max_CCF<- function(a,b)
  {
  d <- ccf(a, b, plot = FALSE, lag.max = 1)
  cor = d$acf[,,1]
  return(max(cor))
} 
```

Comment: ..this does return the max corr value, but I'm wondering how can I use it to build a proper matrix? I'm talking something like what you get with ```heatmap()``` but using the ±1 lag range and selecting the highest value only for the final correlation matrix.

Comment: the code you suggest in these comments seems sensible, you can substitute in the for-loop above, i.e. `cmat[i,j] <- max_CCF(calcium[,i],calcium[,j])` ... ?  If this doesn't work for you, you could try posting a follow-up question ...